# Problemas recibiendo información desde MySQL a través de WebService PHP para aplicación de Xamarin

Tags: php, java, mysql, json, xamarin.forms

He estado trabajando en una aplicación de *Xamarin Forms* para *Android* e *iOS*, usando *PHP* como *web services* para consultar la *base de datos MySQL*, y funciona la mayor parte del tiempo, sin embargo, hay veces que no puedo consultar la *base de datos* para llenar ciertos campos (mayormente *ListView* o *Pickers*).

Por ejemplo, tengo un *Picker* que debe mostrar los nombres de una tabla en la *base de datos* y muestra esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el código del *else* cuando se llena el *Picker de la base de datos* aquí, esta parte del código del relleno del selector:

```
private async void fillListaServidor()
{
    try
    {
        UseManager manager = new UseManager();
        IEnumerable<fullServidor> result = await manager.listarServidores();

        if (result != null)
        {
            txtServidor.ItemsSource = result.ToList();

            Pickerlist = result.ToList();
            Finallist = new List<fullServidor>();

            foreach (var item in Pickerlist)
            {
                var exit = Finallist.Where(i => i.fullname == item.fullname).ToList();
                if (exit.Count == 0)
                {
                    Finallist.Add(item);
                }
            }
            //lstUsuarios.ItemsSource = result;
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e1)
    {
        await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");

    }
}
```

Por si tienen dudas la variable de *excepción `e1`* me muestra esto:

> e1: Java.IO.EOFException: \n not found: size=1 content=0d...

Esto se extiende desde el método `ListarServidores()` que se encuentra en mi controlador y aquí muestro ese fragmento de código:

`fullServidor` es el modelo que tiene todos los elementos de la tabla *DataBase* consultados y el servicio web **listarUsuarios.php** tiene lo siguiente:

```
<?php

$cnx=new PDO("mysql: host=localhost; dbname=databasename","username","password");
$res=$cnx->query("select servidores.id, servidores.nombre, servidores.apellido, usuarios.username, usuarios.activo, accesos.tipo_acceso from servidores INNER JOIN usuarios on servidores.id = usuarios.id_servidor INNER JOIN accesos on usuarios.id_acceso = accesos.id WHERE usuarios.activo = 'Si'");

$datos = array();

foreach ($res as $row){
    array_push($datos, array(
    'id' => $row['id'], 
    'nombre' => $row['nombre'],
    'apellido' => $row['apellido'], 
    'username' => $row['username'], 
    'activo' => $row['activo'], 
    'tipo_acceso' => $row['tipo_acceso'], 
    ));
}
echo utf8_encode(json_encode($datos));
?>
```

¿Qué puede ser mi error en el código que no siempre trae los datos y tengo que recargar? (Por cierto: Tomé el nombre de la base de datos, el nombre de usuario y la contraseña por seguridad, pero cuando uso este *PHP* a través del navegador, siempre obtengo la información de la base de datos).

¿Hay algo que pueda hacer para evitar tener que recargar el *%40* del tiempo?

Comment: El código que compartes al final no puede estar trayendo datos, no veo que uses un método `fetch` para leer el recurso que trae la consulta. Prueba así: **`while ( $row = $res->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { $datos[]=$row; } header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8"); echo json_encode($datos);`** OJO, la forma de llenar el array es mucho más simple porque `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` traerá en cada `$row` un array asociativo. En cuanto a la salida final es mejor usar encabezados y poner dentro la codificación, pero debes cuidar que en el flujo no hay otras salidas por pantalla.

Comment: @A.Cedano gracias por tu información lo probare enseguida aunque con el webservice si se consume porque 80 a 90% de las veces si me regresa información pero probare con esto

Comment: Prueba y nos dices. Me parece extraño que funcione sin usar un método `fetch`. Otra causa de fallo sea que la conexión es lenta, que haya muchas demandas simultáneas, que no haya conexión, etc. Quizá se conveniente en el servidor controlar el estado de la conexión también y en ese caso devolver un JSON indicando que no hay conexión.

Comment: Hola estuve viendo tu codigo y no entiendo como quieres comparar una Lista que aparetemente tiene informacion contra la lista que llega del servidor cuando tu Lista Finallist, la acabas de instanciar y no le has cargados datos aun. Luego de eso, usas todo el tiempo .ToList() mientras iteras con el foreach y deberias hacer var exit = Finallist.Where(i => i.fullname == item.fullname).FirstOrDefault(); pero te dara error porque Finallist esta vacia.

Comment: Entiendo @RamiroBarone sin embargo quisiera encontrar la razon del porque si funciona en ciertas veces si funciona el y me muestra resultados, aun con la lista Finallist, en cierta forma esta funcionando cuando cambie el HTTP Implementation a que use Android y que Native SSL/TLS: sea Native TLS 1.2+ sin embargo sige siendo intermitente que hace estos errores

Comment: podes colocar la excepción completa?

Comment: @RamiroBarone El Codigo es bastante largo para subirlo en un solo Commentario pero puedes ver todo el error en este link: http://securitb.freetzi.com/ErrorenAsistencia.txt

Comment: Tenes que debugear estas dos lineas: InsertarAsistencia.xaml.cs:103 -Training\tbrn_macabeos_app\Clases\UseManager.cs:287, el numero 103 y 287 son las lineas de la variable o donde comienza el metodo que lanza la excepcion. Podes configurar el visual studio en Excepciones para que vaya directamente a la linea donde sale el error.

Comment: @RamiroBarone las lineas de Debug serian las Siguientes:

 InsertarAsistencia.xaml.cs:103 - **IEnumerable<puestos> result = await manager.listarPuestos();**

UseManager.cs:287 - **var result = await client.GetAsync( URL + "listarPuestos.php");**

Aparentemente como que si no lograra hacer la consulta aveces.

Comment: La funcion de client.GetAsync() viene de: 

`private HttpClient getClient()
        {
            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "application/json");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Connection", "close");
            return client;
        }`

Comment: podes pasarme la uri y yo consultar tu servicio?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104752/discussion-between-rene-alas-and-ramiro-barone).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Encontre el problema era con el HTTPClient, lo logre superar creando un Handler:

```
  HttpClientHandler hclient = new HttpClientHandler()
{
Proxy = null,
UseProxy = false,
PreAuthenticate = false
};
```

y al abrir la conexion del http client agrego el handler como parametro:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(hclient);
```

De esta manera se acelara la conexion y no me genera errores. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Modifique un poco tu codigo.

```
public partial class InsertarAsistencia : ContentPage
    {
        public int servidor;
        public int acceso;
        public int usuario;
        public InsertarAsistencia(int parameter1, int parameter2, int parameter3)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            servidor = parameter1;
            acceso = parameter2;
            usuario = parameter3;
            fillListaServidor();
            fillListaPuesto();
            fillListaRadio();
        }
        public InsertarAsistencia()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            fillListaServidor();
            fillListaPuesto();
            fillListaRadio();
        }
        //Variables para picker Servidor
        public int id_servidor;
        public int itemsedc;

    //Variables para picker Puesto
    public int id_puesto;
    public int itemsedc1;

    //Variables para picker Culto
    public int id_culto;
    public int itemsedc2;

    //Variables para picker Radios
    public int id_Radios;
    public int itemsedc3;

    public string fecha;
    public int dianum;

    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();

    }

    //Metodos de Llenado y Seleccion ID Servidor
    private async void fillListaServidor()
    {
        try
        {
            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            IEnumerable<fullServidor> result = await manager.listarServidores();

            if (result != null)
            {
                txtServidor.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************");
            Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
            await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");
        }
    }

    private void servidorPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var servi = (servidor)txtServidor.SelectedItem;
        itemsedc = servi.id;
    }

    //Metodos de Llenado y Seleccion ID Puesto
    private async void fillListaPuesto()
    {
        try
        {
            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            IEnumerable<puestos> result = await manager.listarPuestos();

            if (result != null)
            {
                txtPuesto.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************");
            Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
            await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");
        }
    }

    private void puestoPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var puesto = (puestos)txtPuesto.SelectedItem;
        itemsedc1 = puesto.id;
    }

    //Metodos de Llenado y Seleccion ID Radio
    private async void fillListaRadio()
    {
        try
        {
            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            IEnumerable<equipos> result = await manager.listarEquipos();

            if (result != null)
            {
                txtRadio.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************");
            Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
            await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");
        }
    }

    private void radioPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var radio = (equipos)txtRadio.SelectedItem;
        itemsedc3 = radio.id;
    }

    //Metodos de Llenado y Seleccion ID Radio
    private async void fillListaCulto(int diaculto)
    {
        try
        {
            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            IEnumerable<cultos> result = await manager.listarCultosPorDia(diaculto);

            if (result != null)
            {
                txtCulto.ItemsSource = result.ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("*************************************");
            Console.WriteLine(e1.ToString());
            await DisplayAlert("Error en Lista", "Favor vuelva a cargar Servidor no listo", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");
        }
    }

    private void cultoPicker_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var culto = (cultos)txtCulto.SelectedItem;
        itemsedc2 = culto.id;
    }

    private void fechaSelected_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var diaconver = txtFecha.Date;
        dianum = (int)diaconver.DayOfWeek;

        fillListaCulto(dianum);
    }

    private async void bntAgregarServicio_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            id_servidor = itemsedc;
            id_puesto = itemsedc1;
            id_Radios = itemsedc3;
            id_culto = itemsedc2;
            fecha = txtFecha.Date.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            var diaConvertir = txtFecha.Date;
            var diaenNum = (int)diaConvertir.DayOfWeek;

            UseManager manager = new UseManager();
            manager.registrarAsistencia(id_servidor, fecha, id_culto, diaenNum, id_puesto, id_Radios);

            await DisplayAlert("Registro", "Registro Exitoso", "Aceptar", "Cancelar");

            await Navigation.PushAsync(new MenuAsistencia(servidor, acceso, usuario));
        }
        catch (Exception e1) { Console.WriteLine(e1.Message.ToString()); }
    }
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias Ramiro!!!